# Como fazer com que o pdfkit ignore as extensões?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho o seguinte código

```
import pdfkit

options = {
    'page-size': 'Letter',
    'margin-top': '0.75in',
    'margin-right': '0.75in',
    'margin-bottom': '0.75in',
    'margin-left': '0.75in',
    'encoding': "UTF-8",
    'custom-header' : [
        ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip')
    ],
    'cookie': [
        ('cookie-name1', 'cookie-value1'),
        ('cookie-name2', 'cookie-value2'),
    ],
    'no-outline': None,
    #'load-error-handling': 'ignore'
}

def textToPdf(source, destiny):
    path_wkthmltopdf = r'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
    config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkthmltopdf)
    pdfkit.from_file(source + '.txt', destiny, configuration=config, options=options)
```

Fiz alguns testes utilizando arquivos com extensão 'txt' e funcionou muito bem, porem quando tento com outra extensão como por exemplo 'php' da a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Failed loading page

Pensei que poderia ser o arquivo, mas se eu pego o mesmo arquivo 'txt' e mudo a extensão para php para de funcionar, para solucionar eu fiz a seguinte gambiarra:

```
def textToPdf(source, destiny):
    os.rename(source, source + '.txt')
    path_wkthmltopdf = r'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
    config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkthmltopdf)
    pdfkit.from_file(source + '.txt', destiny, configuration=config, options=options)
    os.rename(source + '.txt', source)
```

Que funciona muito bem, ele coloca a extensão 'txt' no arquivo e depois remove, mas não queria alterar o arquivo original, e querendo ou não é um processamento desnecessário.

Estou utilizando este script para percorrer pastas e sub-pastas, outro problema ao utilizar este método de renomear é que se o script for finalizado no meio do processo algum arquivo pode ficar com a extensão txt.

Como posso fazer para que o pdfkit ignore as extensões?

[Código completo](https://github.com/wictorChaves/FilesToPdf)

**Update**

```
def fileToString(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        return f.read().replace('\n', '<br/>')
    return ''

def textToPdf(source, destiny):
    path_wkthmltopdf = r'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
    config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkthmltopdf)
    pdfkit.from_string(fileToString(source), destiny, configuration=config, options=options)
```

Desta forma também funcionou, convertendo antes o arquivo para string, mas queria jogar o arquivo diretamente para não ter dois processamentos.

> Outro problema de fazer desta forma é porque é perdida a formatação,
>   no momento para solucionar eu estou criando um arquivo temporário e o
>   convertendo.

**Update**

Para "resolver" o problema estou criando um arquivo temporário, copio o arquivo original para uma pasta com a extensão "txt", converto, e envio pdf para o destino com o nome certo.

Answer (score 0):

O mais provável é que o `pdfkit.from_file` esteja usando alguma função de "executar o arquivo", do sistema operacional, em vez de simplesmente ler o arquivo.

A documentação diz que você pode passar, em vez do nome de um arquivo, um arquivo já aberto - aí provavelmente ele só vai usar o método `read` do parâmetro passado:

```
pdfkit.from_file(open(source), destiny, configuration=config, options=options)
```

Se a acentuação não estiver certa, passe o parâmetro adequado para o `open` (ex. `open(source, encoding='utf-8')`)

Comment: Testei aqui, esta apresentando a seguinte mensagem de erro '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: Estou tentando criar uma função para ler o arquivo e converter para string, mas ele não pega as quebras de linha

Comment: Consegui fazer a quebra de linha usando '<br>' no lugar dos '\n', mas queria que a forma como você fez funcionasse

Comment: Colocando desta forma pdfkit.from_file(open(source, 'r'), destiny, configuration=config, options=options), o código roda, ele converte, mas perde a formação.

Comment: Por conta do primeiro erro - tente por `"rb"` em em vez de `"r"`.

Comment: Tentei, e apresentou o seguinte erro "'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'"